# How can i make this Javascript code less repetitve?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I'm new to Javascript and have been learning by myself through a few courses. I was just curious how can I make the following code less repetitive? Is there a way you would approach the following differently, or would you follow the same method?

```
var imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
var lorem = document.querySelector(".hdr-left");
var ipsum = document.querySelector(".hdr-right");

//When clicking on imgContainer toggle between class to change colour and position
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lorem.classList.toggle("hdr-color-white");
  ipsum.classList.toggle("hdr-color-white");
  lorem.classList.toggle('hdr-left-middle');
  ipsum.classList.toggle('hdr-right-middle');
});
```

Comment: What should be there shorter?

Comment: Nothing in here that needs to be cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a `toggle` function:

```
var imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
var lorem = document.querySelector(".hdr-left");
var ipsum = document.querySelector(".hdr-right");

function toggle(el, className) {
  el.classList.toggle(className);
}

//When clicking on imgContainer toggle between class to change colour and position
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggle(lorem, "hdr-color-white");
  toggle(ipsum, "hdr-color-white");
  toggle(lorem, 'hdr-left-middle');
  toggle(ipsum, 'hdr-right-middle');
});
```

Another is to create an array of operational data:

```
var imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
var lorem = document.querySelector(".hdr-left");
var ipsum = document.querySelector(".hdr-right");

toggleOps = [
  { el: lorem, name: 'hdr-color-white'},
  { el: ipsum, name: 'hdr-color-white'},
  { el: lorem, name: 'hdr-left-middle'},
  { el: ipsum, name: 'hdr-right-middle'}
]


//When clicking on imgContainer toggle between class to change colour and position
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleOps.forEach( )
    function(op) {
      op.el.classList.toggle(op.name);
    }
  )
});
```

Reducing code is always a good thing unless the reduction makes the code difficult to understand.

Data drive code is great since you can add more data and not have to write additional code.

Keeping things DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) is worth the effort. If I write something twice I think of refactoring to move the duplicated code into a function. If I need to duplicate it a third time then I use that time to refactor into a new function and fix all three places to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method doing the repetitive work :

```
var imgContainer = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
var lorem = document.querySelector(".hdr-left");
var ipsum = document.querySelector(".hdr-right");

//When clicking on imgContainer toggle between class to change colour and position
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
 toggleClass(lorem.classList,"hdr-color-white");
 // so on...
}); 


function toggleClass(elementClassList, className){
 elementClassList.toggle(className);
}
```

Comment: This is not making any difference , instead adding few more lines

Comment: Yes. but allows to encapsulate the code into a method, so that any future enhancements are abstracted from the event code.

Comment: `toggle` method is itself an encapsulation. I just feel the `toggleClass` method is redundant here